# Htaccess to reach sitemap.xml in wordpress subfolder

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, .htaccess, sitemap

I have angularjs app (http://TouchTyping.guru) and then /blog subfolder with wordpress installation where I use Google XML Sitemaps to generate sitemap.xml - file is generated on request so it doesn't exist physically, it works on my other wordpress instances.

The problem is that when I go http://TouchTyping.guru/blog/sitemap.xml it redirects to the main page, meanwhile I can access /blog itself without problems. (google webmasters says it's html returned, so it's not a problem of cache)

I have standard .htaccess and tried a lot of things already, but even if they work when trying on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ they never work when deployed

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

 RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: Its not just the sitemap btw.... its every page on the blog except for /blog/ itself

Comment: idd, thx, this used to work so I had to break sth more...

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/.*$` makes your rules effect `/blog` only. If you want it to ignore blog do this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$`

Comment: something smells in worpdress as it's automatically changing htaccess, this is probably the problem, thx for looking at that ;]